# How do I recursively run net.Sockets.connect(port, host)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to recursively run **net.connect(port, host)** so that it retries a set number of times while the connection fails (net.Socket.connect returns false), with the desired output being a Boolean representing whether the connection ultimately succeeded or failed.  Logically, I could use a for loop based on a provided value of **retries**, but I'm trying to avoid an eslint *Disallow Functions in Loops (no-loop-func)* error.  Here's my code for the basic (no retries) implementation of net.connect(port, host).  How would I implement this recursively?

```
const net = require('net');

checkPort(host, port, callback) {
    try {
      const socket = new net.Socket();
      let status = false;
      socket.connect(port, host, () => {
        status = true;
        socket.setTimeout(1000, () => socket.destroy());
      });
      socket.setTimeout(1000);
      socket.on('timeout', () => {
        socket.destroy();
      });
      socket.on('close', () => callback(status, null));

      return callback(status, null);
    } catch (err) {
      return callback(null, err);
    }
  }
```

The following would appear to call the net.connect recursively, but it only does so once before closing:

```
const net = require('net');

const socket = new net.Socket();
const port = 8080;
const host = 'pizza.com';
const retries = 5;
let attempt;
let status = false;

function tryConnect(attempts) {
  socket.connect(port, host);
  socket.setTimeout(100);
  attempt = attempts;
}

// this behave normally
socket.on('connect', () => {
  status = true;
  console.log(status);
  console.log('Connected to', host, 'on', port);
  socket.destroy();
});

// this unexpectedly leads to just one attempt to connect before closing
socket.on('timeout', () => {
  attempt += 1;
  if (attempt <= retries) {
    console.log('Connection failed. Retrying (Attempt ', attempt, 'of', retries, ').');
    tryConnect(attempt);
  } else {
    console.log('Connection to', host, 'on port', port, 'failed.');
    socket.destroy();
  }
});

socket.on('close', () => {
  console.log('Connection closed');
});

socket.on('error', () => {
  console.log(status);
});

tryConnect(0);
```

What should I have done differently in structuring this?  Also, does a net.Socket have to be destroyed, ended, or closed before I can reattempt a connection?

Comment: You can use `setInterval()` to attempt to connect every x seconds, or use `setTimeout()` to schedule a new connection when the current attempt has failed. Define the function that tries to connect separately so you can simply pass it as first argument.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this!  What would be the best way to keep track of how many times a connection has been attempted, so that I can compare that to a provided value of maximum attempts to define the end case?

Comment: Just introduce a variable like `var attempts = 0;` then increment / check it each time.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried this, but it wouldn't try to reconnect after the first retry (it tries when attempt = 0 and when attempt = 1, only):

`
function tryConnect(attempts) {
  this.attempt = attempts;
  socket.setTimeout(timeout);
  socket.connect(port, host);
}
socket.on('timeout', () => {
  attempt += 1;
  if (attempt <= retries) {
    console.log('Connection failed. Retrying (Attempt ', attempt, 'of', retries, ').');
    tryConnect(attempt);
  } else {
    console.log('Connection to', host, 'on port', port, 'failed.');
    socket.destroy();
  }
});

tryConnect(0);
`

Comment: I was expecting my above comment to be structured in code (I used the mini-Markdown described in the popup) >_> . Please excuse the formatting, and thanks for your help, everyone!

Comment: Thanks for the help!  After some trial and error, the solution was placing the event listeners inside the function declaration, and calling the function recursively with `tryConnect(1 + attempt)` in the 'timeout' and 'error' events!